# What do these Web Driver selectors select?

Tags: webdriver

What do these web driver selectors select?

```
get talktoSales(){return $("(//div)[56]")} 
get popUpclick() {return $("//div[@class='spu-container']")}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the link to the webiste it would be difficult to point to the exact element selected by these selectors.

The first selector `"(//div)[56]"` selects the 56th div element in the page

The second one `"//div[@class='spu-container']"` selects the first div element that has the class name as 'spu-container'

Comment: RE: `"(//div)[56]"` Would counting start @ 0 or 1? i.e would it count the 56th or 57th div?